# How can I create a box big enough to contain whatever content I put in it?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-6

Here is a link to my problematic page:

> http://www.studioteknik.com/lamouvance/programmation.php

I'm trying to have a box be as big as the content injected into it (with PHP). It works on IE6 but not in Firefox... maybe I have done too many tricks, that the world is now upside down...

Please, help! I'm sure it a one line solution... Thanks in advance!

- Note that the foot at the to should be in fact a full background picture (ok it's ugly, but the client ask for it), you can click on service, the image is just fine !

---

I hijack my own question.... IE6 is playing me mad, the mission (first in the menu) there is a calendar, the aout 2009 is supposed to be ON ONE LINE.... why its on two line in ie6 ?

Comment: What in particular doesn't work?  I just looked in Firefox and didn't see any OBVIOUS problems, but I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: For the problem, it a background picture at the the that shoul be at the bottom (foot)

Comment: The question title is priceless. As Richard Feynman would say, "if you've put some content in it, the box is big enough to contain it by definition" :-)

Comment: This is NOT the original title... somebody have change it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see the issue, try:

```
.content {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set a height, a box will stretch to fit content in it. If the box only contains floating elements, either add this just before the end:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.clear {
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

Or, a simpler solution is to add the style `overflow: auto` to the box. (Note this will show scroll bars if you have set an explicit height on said box.)